# switch/case inside for loop not working properly

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, switch-statement

I need to check each element of a matrix to see if it's something specific or not.
I have to use switch/case for this piece of code.
I have a vector like this :

```
COUNTER=[counterA counterB counterC counterWaste]
```

I tried this :

```
for n=1:size(COUNTER,2)
   switch COUNTER(1,n)
       case counterA
          disp(['counterA is ' , num2str(counterA)])
       case counterB
          disp(['counterB is ' , num2str(counterB)])
       case counterC
          disp(['counterC is ' , num2str(counterC)])
       case counterWaste
          disp(['counterWaste is ' , num2str(counterWaste)])
    end
end
```

counterA & counterB & counterC & counterWaste are some variables which contain a random number.
It gived the right number as I already know the right number of each counter variable, but the strings are not correct. for example it once it gives

```
counterA is 1
counterB is 2
counterA is 1
counterB is 2
```

next time

```
counterA is 4
counterB is 1
counterB is 1
counterWaste is 0
```

and ...

I don't know where the problem is from. anybody has any idea ?

Comment: It seems right. Could you generate the COUNTER array, say two or three times, and provide the values? Maybe edit your question to add that?

Comment: actually I figured out that each time I run the code, those elements with same number will have same string. (as @smagnan said in his answer) only when I have 4 different numbers, the result is correct. I'm not looking for another way to check the elements of a matrix one by one ...

Comment: @Pay4m: You can take a llok at my answer, I added a solution, even if NOT an elegant one at all (:

Comment: Just to make it clear: do you want the string to be printed **only** when the counter is equal to the expected value? For example, if counter(1,2) == counterB, print it?

Comment: no no it's not necessary. I just want to print the numbers by checking the elements name, then if the name of for example first element is "counterA", I need to print the value of counterA. the numbers are inside variables before. Your answer is right. I chose it as the best one <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misusing case, friend. You're trying to switch by the variable name, but the variable name simply points to value that variable holds. Try this:

```
for n=1:size(COUNTER,2)
   switch n
       case 1
          disp(['counterA is ' , num2str(counterA)])
       case 2
          disp(['counterB is ' , num2str(counterB)])
       case 3
          disp(['counterC is ' , num2str(counterC)])
       case 4
          disp(['counterWaste is ' , num2str(counterWaste)])
    end
end
```

Note that I'm switching by a value that behaves predictably. Good luck, and happy coding.

Edit: Just to clarify, I don't think this is the best solution, Raf's is better. It just meets the asker constraint of using switch/case.

Comment: Ah, I though it was bounded at 4. Have you already found a solution to the open ended case? I'm interested, because I don't think the switch/case structure is built for for open-ended problems.

Comment: wow, I deleted my comment because when I put your code, it incredibly worked :))) but HOW ? for example, its giving this : counterA is 8
counterB is 19
counterC is 6
counterWaste is 2

How MATLAB finds out that the "n" is index of the COUNTER vector ?

Comment: n goes from 1 to size(COUNTER,2), which are the index of COUNTER. Take a look at Rafael Monteiro code to understand it better (:

Comment: Good Question! MATLAB knows because we're assessing the switch/case-by-n inside a for-loop which uses n as it's iterator. It's build into the structure of the script. Neat, huh? One limitation: for each additional counter, you would have to hard-code another case. But that's ok, because that's how switch/cases are supposed to work anyway.

Comment: As I need switch/case format, I tried my codes and didn't work and I came here to ask other guys. but of course there are several other ways which I know how to write them .. thank you so much. But I've still not understood how MATLAB finds out that the "n" is the index of COUNTER vector while we don't have any point or address to COUNTER vector by using "n" !!! when I was using COUNTER(1,n) then MATLAB could understand that the n is index of COUNTER columns !! but now ?

Comment: I could use n=1:4 instead of n=1:size(COUNTER,2) as we always have only 4 columns of random numbers between 0 and 500 !

Comment: You could do that. The way you have it now is technically more flexible. Then again, switch/case is decidedly rigid by design, so it really won't matter one way or the other.

Comment: Now, to answer your other question: Imagine the vector COUNTER in your mind. It's a 1x4 vector of numbers. Each one of those numbers has an index. Switch/case is just taking instruction. It thinks, "when the variable n holds the value 3, display ['counterC is ' , num2str(counterC)]. We (human programmers) know that the variable stored in counterC is always going to be at index 3 of the counter structure, so we gave the switch/case those instructions. So, MATLAB doesn't really "understand" the relationship. It's just doing exactly what we told it to. I hope this clears it up for you!

Comment: I know what you say. but what if the "3" is the index of another element in another vector ? right now, I have 5 other vectors, but "n" only refers to COUNTER vector in your code !! it's like MATLAB knows it :D this is my question .. how ? hope you tolerate me :D

Comment: and how MATLAB finds out that "n" is going to be the index number ? it can be just a number not an index number ...

Comment: I can guess my answer. MATLAB does not understand anything. because I need to use switch/case format, you wrote the code like this. right ? as you said, it's an instruction we make to have our result by using this format !

Comment: Oh, it's no trouble at all, I just like to help. The key is this line: "num2str(counterC)]" CounterC is a variable. You are assigning that variable to COUNTER in a previous line (COUNTER=[counterA counterB counterC counterWaste]), you are now using that SAME variable again inside of the n=3 case of the switch/case structure. When the switch/case sees that n == 3 it runs this code: "disp(['counterC is ' , num2str(counterC)])" CounterC in this line will always equal the third element of COUNTER, because you set the third element of counter to CounterC in a previous line.

Comment: wow nice. last question. can I compare the elements of the vector by their string ? for example: switch COUNTER(1,n) case 'counterA' blah blah blah, case 'counterB' blah blah blah . I mean to see if the string of the variable inside the vector is what we expect .

Comment: To compare strings use: `strcmp(StringVarA, StringVarB)` it will return a 1 if the strings stored in StringVarA and StringVarB are the same, a 0 if they aren't. Note: it will break if you use it with numbers, unless you convert them to strings first using `num2str()`

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you have

```
COUNTER=[counterA counterB counterC counterWaste]
```

but `counterA counterB counterC counterWaste` are, as you say, random values, so in your first example

```
counterA is 1
counterB is 2
counterA is 1
counterB is 2
```

you have, I imagine `COUNTER=[1 2 1 2]`
And you use a swich case on the values inside COUNTER, but you have `counterA = counterC = 1` here for example, so your switch case is used like that

```
for n=1:size(COUNTER,2)
   switch COUNTER(1,n)
       case counterA  % counterA = counterC = 1 go there
          disp(['counterA is ' , num2str(counterA)])
       case counterB  % counterB = counterWaste = 2 go there
          disp(['counterB is ' , num2str(counterB)])
       case counterC  % counterC = 1 but never used because counterC go to case counterA
          disp(['counterC is ' , num2str(counterC)])
       case counterWaste % same as case counterC
          disp(['counterWaste is ' , num2str(counterWaste)])
    end
end
```

Actually I think every *`case`* should have a different value (`case` are evaluating the values, not the var name) because if two case have the same value (It is possible here because your values are random) only the first one is evaluated (:

The problem is the same for:

```
counterA is 4
counterB is 1
counterB is 1
counterWaste is 0
```

You have `COUNTER=[4 1 1 0]` so `case counterC` is never evaluated because `case counterB` is, for both `counterB` and `counterC`.
But I may be wrong, long time not used MatLab

I think this should work:

```
for n=1:size(COUNTER,2)
   switch n
       case 1  
          disp(['counterA is ' , num2str(counterA)])
       case 2  
          disp(['counterB is ' , num2str(counterB)])
       case 3  
          disp(['counterC is ' , num2str(counterC)])
       case 4 
          disp(['counterWaste is ' , num2str(counterWaste)])
    end
end
```

Note that there are many other ways to do so. This one is quite complicated for nothing ^^

Comment: Owh perfect, that's right. Can you suggest a way to check a vector elements one by one ?

Comment: I edited my answer with a proposition, even if it isn't a good one it shoud work (:

Comment: unfortunately it's not working. the SWITCH expression is COUNTER(1,n), then how could for example the COUNTER(1,1) be 1 ? this "1" cannot be the address of first element ...

Comment: I made a mistake, as Fletch said, use `switch n` (the index) instead of `COUNTER(1,n)`, it shoud work. Note that in MatLab, Matrix (etc...) start at index 1 not 0

Answer (score 1):

Could you drop the `for` and `switch` statements and do it like this?

```
disp(['counterA is ' , num2str(COUNTER(1,1))]);
disp(['counterB is ' , num2str(COUNTER(1,2))]);
disp(['counterC is ' , num2str(COUNTER(1,3))]);
disp(['counterWaste is ' , num2str(COUNTER(1,4))]);
```